# Draw vertical lines on charts using ng2-charts + chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm working with ng2-charts and chart.js.
I have a line chart and I want to draw some vertical lines. I'd like to have an array with index like this 
`verticalLine = [2,7,12]`
and at the right index I need the vertical line.

I tried many solutions but I don't know how to do.

can someone help me? I live here my code (Simplified).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-vertical-line

thanks